# How do sent this data over to parse server using Android

Tags: java, android, parsing

I'm working on an app where whatevever the user speaks on the phone gets added to the listview(up to this is working fine) and on clicking that item on that list view,send that over to the parse server.

This is my class called Speech

```
`package com.example.projecta;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 import com.parse.Parse;
 import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
 import com.parse.ParseObject;

 public class Speech extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ListView viewlist;

static final int check = 1111;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.speech);
    Parse.initialize(this, "JnmLmnvOjxvRgBMGPl4XzOzvoqPPY7KGG2cqiExL", "8ejsJCanB26YYB6Io3jKov5wcwuajcB1zjRPUyMs");
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Storedata.class);
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    viewlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.speechview);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speechb);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent in = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    in.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    in.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak Louder");
    startActivityForResult(in, check);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        viewlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void createStoredata(View v) {

          Storedata st = new Storedata();
          st.setDescription(viewlist.toString());

          st.saveEventually();

      }





  }
```

`
This is my store data class

```
package com.example.projecta;


import com.parse.ParseObject;

public class Storedata extends  ParseObject{
  public Storedata(){

  }

  public void setDescription(String description){
      put("description", description);
  }

  {
```

}
}

I really need help with this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a listener to your listview itself to click the items

```
viewlist.setClickable(true);
viewlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
      //perform action with your item
  }
});
```